# Word translator tool tracing

Tags: microsoft-office-365, network-traffic

If anyone (on our school wired network/Wi-fi) uses the Microsoft translator tool implemented in Word, would we be able to trace it or are we not able to see such activity going on in the network like we can trace students using google translate or some browser-based translator tool. Haven't been able to catch anyone using it yet so I'm wondering...

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have some network monitoring tool in place then you can check what traffic is being generated related to what you're looking for. For the translation feature you mention investigate what specific service MS Office Word uses or connect to (in case that how it works) so you can make sure if such feature is being used.

In the case of Google translate search for the `https://translate.google.com/` URL in your network traffic so you can confirm if students are using it. You can do the same with any other browser-based translator. Last, if what you need/want is to block this service you can use web filtering (which uses categories) so you don't have to worry about these services being queried since they're going to be blocked.